# Record from database to array

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I want to retrieve a specific record from the database via a button on an index page and store that object in a temp Array and then display the atributes of an object on a specific view. But the record from find method isn't stored in a variable and i don't know why ... I am  getting error for nil:NilClass.(In my project I want to be able to make a list of ordered patients for a day and display them in a view  )

Here is my code :

patient_index.html.erb (from scaffold)

```
  <tbody>
<% @patients.each do |patient| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= patient.name %></td>
    <td><%= patient.last_name %></td>        
    <td><%= patient.id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', patient %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_patient_path(patient) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', patient, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    <td> <%= button_to 'Order', order_path(id: patient)%></td>
    <th><%= @temp[0].name %></th> #testing if it shows the value here
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

`post 'order', to: 'patients#order'`

patients_controller.rb

```
    def index
    @patients = Patient.all
    end

    def show 
    end 

    def edit ... #generated by scaffold

    def destroy ...

    def update ...

   def order
    @temp = []
    @the_patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
    @temp << @the_patient

    redirect_to patients_url

    end
```

error  image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LDVn.jpg (slightly different names ..i got the code and variables in my language  )

Thanks for help and advise :)

Comment: where are you defining `@patients`? Also please post the complete error message with relevant backtrace.

Comment: It is complaining that `@patients` no longer exists because you do not define it in `#order`.

Comment: the variable `@temp` is lost when you redirect, if you want, move that block of code to the index action

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to tell but are you maybe doing

```
redirect_to patients_url
```

in your `#order` action but you mean:

```
redirect_to patient_url
```

Which would be your `#show` action. I get that you are using a different language. Maybe the problem is a pluralization error?

If not, here's my answer:

You are trying to build an index page without `@temp` defined. Think about it, you call for Index, so it builds the index page. what is `@temp` at that time? It doesn't get set until you click on the button, which can't exist yet because `#index` does not define it. But even after you define it in `#order` you then redirect to `#index` where it gets reset to `[]`. You need to restructure your app. A simple hack would be to redirect to a new page that has it's own code that included `@temp` and take any reference to `@temp` out of `#index`.

Along the lines of:

```
patients_url -> index action -> patients_url with button press -> 
  order action -> order_display_url
```

Comment: a tried to define the `@temp` globally in application_controller  `@temp = [] `and then in an `#order` controller i tried just simply add a string to that array `@temp << "hello"` but i am getting error : undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass so i think the problem is with Arrays in rails or something

Comment: The problem in most likely not Arrays in rails. Just because you define something at that level, doesn't mean it will work. Rails is convention over configuration. The Index view is the index view. If you want to add something to it with a button click after it has loaded, you need to use AJAX, or have a different view that gets the info from the Order action. You are trying to make rails do something it is not designed to do.

Comment: Thanks for help anyway ;) I figure it out different way by adding attribute ordered to database of patients and with the button i just set the atribute to true and then i just use `Patient.all.where(ordered: true)` to assign to a variable